# where can I download andEngine related "so" library files

Tags: android, andengine

can some please help me. where can I download the "so" files related to andEngine ?

Thanks
-Chandu

Comment: I need them too, as said in some guides...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build them yourself. See [/jni/build.bat](http://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/source/browse/jni/build.bat) and [/jni/build.sh](http://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/source/browse/jni/build.bat).

Answer (score 0):

for individual andengine examples:
http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/#src%2Forg%2Fanddev%2Fandengine%2Fexamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed

the jar is located here. right-click and choose "save as":
http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/lib/andengine.jar

Comment: The jar link doesnt work, the latest can be found at the link though http://wiki.andengine.org/AndEngine_Jars